# How to return one record if all the records for one key meet a condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking for a way to handle the following scenario. I have a database table which I need to return only one record only if all records for that document meet a condition.

I got this table:

```
    Docnum  Qty
    220      1
    220      1
    220      1
    220     10
    221      1
    221      0
    221      0
    221     10
    222      1
    222      1
    222      1
    222     10
```

The query result must returns only those records where all qty be different to zero, in this case "docnum" 220 and 222:

```
    Docnum
    220
    222
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT docnum
FROM table
GROUP BY docnum
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN Qty = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fff8cbe5f053804045738d5328658f59)**

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It works perfectly. I had doubts about using HAVING clause.  I'm a novice, sou your help was very useful. Thanks Again

Answer (score 4):

Using `NOT IN`

```
select distinct Docnum
from yourTable
where Docnum not in (select Docnum from yourTable where Qty = 0)
```

Comment: If quantity could be null then this may be problematic.

Comment: true @xQbert but I didn't assume this since I would have expected there to be a `NULL` instead of `0` and there weren't `NULL` in the sample data.

Comment: @scimon `0` instead of `null`? but I agree with the sentiment :P

Comment: Fortunately, Qty never be a NULL value. Thank you guys for your help

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `not exists`

```
select distinct t.Docnum  
from table t
where not exists (select 1 from table where Docnum = t.Docnum and Qty = 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select Docnum  
from MyTable
group by Docnum
having min(abs(Qty)) <> 0
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4212f/6)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
    ([Docnum] int, [Qty] int)
;

INSERT INTO MyTable
    ([Docnum], [Qty])
VALUES
    (220, 1),
    (220, 1),
    (220, 1),
    (220, 10),
    (221, 1),
    (221, 0),
    (221, 0),
    (221, 10),
    (222, 1),
    (222, 1),
    (222, 1),
    (222, 10)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select Docnum  
from MyTable
group by Docnum
having min(abs(Qty)) <> 0
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/4212f/6/0)**:

```
| Docnum |
|--------|
|    220 |
|    222 |
```

Comment: I like  how this handles potential negatives.

Answer (score 1):

and a 3rd approach since the other two would work as well.

```
SELECT distinct docnum
FROM yourTable A
WHERE not exists (SELECT 1 
                  FROM yourtable B
                  WHERE B.qty=0
                    and A.DocNum = B.DocNum)
```

This uses a correlated subquery to identify all documents where not a single record for a docNum contains a 0.  It would benefit from indexes on qty and docNum.

Comment: Thanks, im going to try this approach too.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `Qty` is never negative:

```
select Docnum
from tab
group by Docnum
Having min(Qty) > 0
```

If it might be negative, too:

```
select Docnum
from tab
group by Docnum
Having min(abs(Qty)) <> 0
```

Comment: Yes, qty is never negative.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this query:

```
select * from "table_name" where Qty <> 0;
```

Comment: This would not work. it would return Docnum 221 as well.